# Simple Java Application to read RSSI from BLE Beacon

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a simple yet still unsolved problem. I want to continuously read the RSSI from a BLE Beacon. To do this, I want to use a JavaSE application. I don't want to use Android because the application will run on a Raspberry Pi 2.
I have already found libraries of sandeepmistry and also found the Kura Project. But it seems that sandeepmistry doesn't support reading the RSSI and Kura is a pain in the ass to work with (or I'm to silly for it).
Can anyone tell me a simple way to get the data I need or give me hint where I can find understandable tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like there is actually no way to do this in JavaSE. So I switched to a node.js module called [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble/). It is pretty cool so if someone else is hitting this issue, give it a try.